# How to write expressions in tensor notation?

Tags: notation, tensor-products, tensors, index-notation

I’m a self-taught math student and i want to learn how to work and calculate with tensors.
I’m pretty familiar with the theory behind them, but something about the the different notations just does not sink in. I thought of an experiment that might help me understand it better, and i would really appreciate your help.
The experiment is very straightforward:

Suppose i have a simple finite field extension $$K=\frac{\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)}{\mathbb{Q}}$$
If $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are in $K$, then, for some natural number $d$, one can write:
$$\vec{a}=a_0+a_1\alpha+\cdots+a_d\alpha^d$$
$$\vec{b}=b_0+b_1\alpha+\cdots+b_d\alpha^d$$
with $\{a_0;\cdots;a_d;b_0;\cdots;b_d\}\in\mathbb{Q}$.
A typical multiplication in $K$ would go like this:
$$\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}=\sum_{i+j\leq 2d}a_ib_j\alpha^{i+j}$$
But this is only the sum of all products, and all products are contained in the components of a tensor product of two vectors; so it’s clearly *some* contraction (or multilinear form… please, adress the difference in the answer) on the 2-tensor $\mathcal{T}\in K^{\otimes 2}$:
$$\mathcal{T}=\vec{a}\otimes\vec{b}$$
All this said, my question is the following: how can i express $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}$ in the language of tensors? If that is too broad, how can i express that product like a tensor contraction or multilinear form?

Comment: You can express the operation of multiplication in $K$ as a map $K \otimes K \to K$, if that is what you are after.

Comment: Yes. That is a bi-linear map… but that is just the map’s definition. There should be an actual map defined as the contraction $\gamma:K\otimes K\rightarrow K$ Such that $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}=\gamma(\vec{a}\otimes\vec{b})$

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. There is an actual map for the multiplication in $K$. Are you looking for the matrix which represents it with respect to the basis $\{1, \alpha, \ldots, \alpha^d\}$? If so, you can find it by writing $\alpha^n$ in terms of the basis for $d < n \leq 2d$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some time looking in forums and papers, i found something that could be a proper answer:

Let $V$ be the matrix vector space:
$$V=K\otimes K$$
And $*:K^2\rightarrow V$ the outer product of vectors, we then write:
$$\vec{a}*\vec{b}=\begin{pmatrix}
a_0b_0 & a_0b_1 & \cdots & a_0b_d
\\a_1b_0 & a_1b_1 & \cdots & a_1b_d
\\ \vdots& \vdots &\ddots & \vdots
\\a_db_0 & a_db_1 & \cdots & a_db_d
\end{pmatrix}$$
The basis of $V$ as a tensor product is
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \cdots &\alpha_d
\\\vdots &\ddots & \vdots
\\\alpha_d &\cdots & \alpha_{2d}
\end{pmatrix}$$
We can then define the product in k as the inner product in $V$:
$$\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}=\langle\vec{a}*\vec{b},B\rangle_F$$